# php png image quality 50%

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a php script I'm using to convert an uploaded image into half it's quality so I can save server space, but it isn't working I'm new to PHP so hopefully someone can help me where I am going wrong.

```
if(isset($_FILES['t1']['name'])){
    $file = rand(0, 10000000).$_FILES['t1']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['t1']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
        if($fp = fopen($file,"rb", 0))
        {
           $picture = fread($fp,filesize($file));
           fclose($fp);
           $img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
           imagepng($img, $file, 6); //6 quality setting
           imagedestroy($img);
           $tag1 = '<img src="'.$file.'" alt="" class="default" />';
//unlink($file);
echo "<script>$(document).ready(function() {var write = $('.item:nth-child(1)').html();localStorage.item1Pantry = write;});</script>";      
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG is lossless compression.  When you set "quality" to 6, you are really just using a mediocre compression method, likely taking up more space.  Use 9 for the highest compression (at the expense of slightly more CPU usage, which is hardly noticeable unless you're doing batch processing).

You might also look into [Yahoo!'s image compression](http://www.smushit.com/), for more lossless optimizations.

Also, you really shouldn't be allowing users to specify file names, even in part.  You wouldn't be too pleased if someone uploaded `remote_control_script.php`.  Never trust what users upload.

Comment: Is there a way I can only force users to upload png files?

Comment: @Blynn, No.  All you can do is detect the file type server-side later (by actually examining the file data, not just looking at the extension!).  Even then, there have been known vulnerabilities in image libraries in the past.  Name your files in sequential number order or something, with no file name extensions, outside of the web doc root.  Serve them with a PHP script that gets the file data from a database.  Then, you can even return them with a suggested file name with what the user originally had if you want, while preventing server-side execution.